# Asynchronous HTTP response Android

Tags: android, http, asynchronous, service, android-service

I am trying to do the following and am looking into other people's experiences:

I want to have an HTTP server running on Android that receives GET requests from a client. From there, the server must deliver the query parameters to a `Service` that will do some processing (sometimes quite heavy). When the service is done, it sends back the data to the server that will then return the response.

Of course, the startService(intent) call is asynchronous so I'm wondering how to tell the server to wait for the processing to be done before sending back the response. At the moment, the inter process messaging is done with the `Messenger` and `Message` classes.

What sort of design would be able to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a bound service (one that implements `onBind()`) and a `transact` call on the returned `IBinder` object. Or write your own AIDL to describe the service's synchronous interface.

You want to bind to your service on app startup, before the HTTP requests start coming, since the bind operation itself is async.

By the way, why does the functionality have to be in the service? If the service is in the same app, can you move it directly to the HTTP server class?

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I was also going to investigate AIDL. Functionality cannot be in the server because I might need to dispatch intents to a bunch of different services. What's a transact call?

Comment: Once you connect to a service via `Context.bindService()`, you get an `IBinder` object back. `IBinder has a method `transact()`.

Comment: would you recommend unbinding from the service at every HTTP request or leave the connection open?

Comment: If the service is within the same app - no.